# Joining 3 tables, query not responding

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having problem trying to join 3 tables, every time I run the query on my server I just get a huge pause which requires manual termination.

here is the table strictures

```
books   : isbn(PK)
books_a : id(PK), isbn, price, condition
books_l : id(PK), isbn, price, condition
```

here is the query

```
SELECT 
   b.isbn, 
   a.price       AS a_price, 
   a.condition   AS a_condition, 
   l.price       AS l_price, 
   l.condition   AS l_condition 

FROM 
   books b  

   LEFT JOIN a_books a ON b.isbn  = a.isbn 
   LEFT JOIN l_books l ON b.isbn  = l.isbn
```

What could be the problem with my query? (note I do have over 6,000 records in each table)

Comment: That's a lower-case L, not the number 1

Comment: What indexes and keys do you have defined on the tables?

Comment: b.isbn(PK), a.isbn(FK), l.isbn(FK)

Comment: @mk_89 do you really define it as `PK` and `FK` on the tables or just *verbal* assignment. Can you run this query? `DESCRIBE books;`, `DESCRIBE books_l;`,`DESCRIBE books_a;` and post the results here?

Comment: @JohnWoo Sorry I mean only books.isbn has a key (PK)

Comment: @mk_89 then you should define keys for `books_l` and `books_a` :)

Comment: @JohnWoo the primary keys for those tables are id, since a_books and l_books may have multiple books with the same isbn it would not be possible to assign the isbn field with a key

Comment: @mk_89 then define atleast `non-unique` index on those columns since they are being used in joining your tables.

Comment: @JohnWoo well I indexed the isbn fields and everything is running. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet that one or some of these columns are not indexed. `a_books.isbn`, `books.isbn`, `l_books.isbn`

try running this statements,

```
ALTER table a_books ADD INDEX IDX_abk (isbn);
ALTER table books ADD INDEX IDX_bk (isbn);
ALTER table l_books ADD INDEX IDX_lbk (isbn);
```

[*Read this article:* **How does database indexing work?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, yes both tables a & l may not have the isbn number

Comment: @mk_89 the existence of values for `isbn` on other tables does not matter at all. What matters most is the `index` you have defined in your tables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be if isbn does not have an index.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly index is the culprit with > 6K records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason could be that after joining first table it will be huge scan for the second join. So it will return you a lot of rows.